# How to redirect users to original request after authentication, Angular-Fullstack Yeoman?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, yeoman-generator

I'm using the Angular-Fullstack yeoman generator as the basis for my project:
https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

I cannot figure out how to redirect users to the link they originally requested after logging in.

Example of what I want to happen:

- Unauthenticated user requests http://myapp/videos/video1
- User is directed to log in
- User successfully authenticates
- User is automatically redirected to http://myapp/videos/video1

I am using both the boilerplate local login and boilerplate OAuth.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You mean you cannot figure out how to implement the whole process or just how to have access to the initially requested link?

Comment: I can't figure out how to access the link, then where after authentication to do the redirect.  I am sure I could store the requested link in a cookie or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, here are the steps I took to solve this problem.  <s>For some reason, Stack Overflow isn't formatting my last 2 code blocks below.</s>  I made a gist with the code below (note 3 separate files need to be modified)
https://gist.github.com/dcoffey3296/d27c141ef79bec3ff6a6

1. store the url to return to in a cookie within the `.run()` method of `client/app/app.js`

   ```
   .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth, $cookieStore) {
     // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
       Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
         if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {

           // store the requested url if not logged in
           if ($location.url() != '/login')
           {
               $cookieStore.put('returnUrl', $location.url());
           }
           $location.path('/login');
         }
       });
     });
   });
   ```
2. for Oauth, check for this cookie and redirect if it exists in `server/auth/auth.service.js`

   ```
   function setTokenCookie(req, res) {
     if (!req.user) { 
         return res.json(404, { message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'}); 
     }

     var token = signToken(req.user._id, req.user.role);
     res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(token));

     // return the user to the request page (oAuth) or homepage
     if (typeof req.cookies.returnUrl != 'undefined')
     {
         res.redirect(req.cookies.returnUrl.replace(/"/g, "") || '/');
     }
     else
     {
         res.redirect('/');
     }
   }
   ```
3. for local login, check for cookie in the `.then()` part of `$scope.login()`, file: `client/app/account/login/login.controller.js`

   ```
   .then( function() {
         // Logged in, redirect to home
         if (typeof $cookieStore.get('returnUrl') != 'undefined' && $cookieStore.get('returnUrl') != '')
         {
             $location.path($cookieStore.get('returnUrl'));
             $cookieStore.remove('returnUrl');
         }
         else
         {
             $location.path('/');
         }
       })
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't imagine how much time you saved me!! One note: in my implementation I needed `$window.location.href = $cookieStore.get('returnUrl');`  instead of your `$location.path($cookieStore.get('returnUrl'));` (step 3) in order to get the redirect to work.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a similar case, is that when I redirected user to login page, I attached to the url (as a query parameter) the initial path that user was trying to access eg. `path_to_login?requested_url=/videos/video1`. So when the login was completed successfully I just read `requested_url` query parameter and if that existed, user was redirected to the specified path.

Comment: Thanks gosling, I totally get what you're saying, I cannot figure out where in the boilerplate code for the angular-fullstack codebase to get the query and where to recall it from.