# Angular-Fullstack Login / Logout without redirect

Tags: angular-fullstack

Is there a way to use the authentication module of Angular-Fullstack for login / logout that does not redirect?

I would like to do other stuff in the callback instead. The redirect disturbs my process.

Answer (score 0):

Would redirect users to original request after authentication work for you? if so see: [How to redirect users to original request after authentication, Angular-Fullstack Yeoman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725524/how-to-redirect-users-to-original-request-after-authentication-angular-fullstac)

If not, then I think you can still use #1 of that answer to get to your goal.